# Find non FQDN server names and update it with FQDN name in ServerName column

Tags: python, pandas

I want to find non FQDN server names and update it with FQDN name in ServerName column in excel sheet.

```
Col A Col B ServerName
abc xyz hqbserverx.us.com
xyz abc hqbservery
abc abc hqbserverz.us.com
xyz abc hqbserverx
abc abc hqbservery
xyz abc hqbserverz.us.com
abc abc hqbservery
xyz abc habserverz.us.com
```

Answer (score 0):

##Finally i got the below solution

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('path\file.xlsx')
df_array = df.to_numpy()
for index, value in enumerate(df_array[:, 3]):
    s = ".com"
    if value.find(s) == -1:
        df_array[index][3] += '.com'

print(df)
df.to_excel('path\file.xlsx',index=False)
```